# Query to identify changes to a set of data?

Tags: sql, database, excel, ms-access

I have two reports. One which was generated three weeks ago, the other a few days ago. These reports share the same fields (Last Name, First Name, SSN, etc.) but the data is obviously different. We've edited particular fields. A customer's SSN may have been edited to reflect a data entry mistake. Their address information might have been updated.

We've yet to install an audit table as part of our database, so we need to determine another way to identify changes between the reports. There are a couple of glaring issues.

1) When we exported the data into Excel, the record ID was not retained. A single customer may have multiple records to account for different addresses, so their SSN wouldn't be unique.
2) We don't only need to identify the changes. We need to categorize them. If there was a change made to SSN, report that separately than changes made to address.

So, if I were to import the two files into a database, is there a query that can fix this for me? My team and I have brainstormed on this for some time now and we've thought of nothing. Without a unique record ID, on which field(s) are we meant to link?

If you'd like me to be more specific as to any part of the question, please let me know and I'll do whatever I can to help you assist me.

The reports are in an Excel file that was exported from a query ran in MS Access 2013.

Thank you.

Comment: First, if you are going to import into a database base, use one that is more compliant such as SQL Server Express.  Second, importing the data into a database will not *fix* the problem.  If you are know SQL, then it might make it easier to manipulate the data and identify what you want to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have no PK on your report as you lost it when exporting to Excel. Assuming you cannot recover it, you are out of luck unless there is something else that can quantify as a PK.

What I would do if I were you is import both of the report files as separate tables:
table_old
table_new

Then I'd do a minus statement to eliminate exact copies:

```
select * from table_old
minus
select * from table_new
```

This will show you records that existed on your old report, but have either been deleted or modified. You could then the do converse

```
select * from table_new
minus
select * from table_old
```

This will give you changes and/or new/removed records.

That being said, the only real way to categorize the records would be to incorporate the SSN to this. Having no PK will make this a very inexact science, but in losing the PK you're going to have to live with this being close instead of exact.

Comment: Awesome response. Had no idea that the minus function existed. So now I have a question. The minus function will show me both records that were added and records that were removed. That's a large chunk of the problem. So with these new record sets, can I perform another minus function on say, the SSN, specialty and address fields? That should be a unique combination and it would pull all records where one of those fields were edited. Am I correct in thinking this or is there a simpler solution?

Comment: It makes sense that you could do that. All MINUS does is says "what is in population that doesn't have an exact copy in population B"

So yes, you could rig something up where you suddenly use the SSN as a PK and look for address changes, or vice versa, and it'd work. Won't be the cleanest solution, but in programming clean data is a rarity these days!